# How to access the outlook folders other than default ones (like Inbox, Sent) using python win32com?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

This is how I am able to access the inbox:

```
   outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
   inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
```

When I tried to access the user created folders in Outlook using the below code:

```
   outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Folder = outlook.Folders[1]
   print (Folder)
```

I got this error:

```
  raise IndexError("list index out of range")

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Globally, you can do:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
```

Then you can check the name of this folder by

```
print (root_folder.Name)
```

And to know the names of the subfolders you have:

```
for folder in root_folder.Folders:
    print (folder.Name)
```

Finally, let's say you want to access a subfolder named `folder_of_soldy` in your `root_folder`, you do:

```
soldy_folder = root_folder.Folders['folder_of_soldy']
```

And so on if you have other subfolders in `folder_of_soldy`.

Hope you find what you need

Comment: Thank you so much Ben. T. I have been trying to get this right for almost a week. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks Ben.T, your code helped me as well.